# Node.js posting date wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm posting a date to `elasticsearch` and I'n using `Date.now()`

```
var unixtime = Date.now();
```

I'm getting the output like this: `1373508091156`

Then I use this:

```
var date = new Date(unixtime*1000);
```

The output now is this:

```
Thu Sep 27 45494 05:19:16 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

---

I'm not sure why I'm getting this is really wrong date :/

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop multiplying it by 1,000.  Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hmm true.. not sure why I found from other post when I googled that they said I should *1000. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Ali, JavaScript time is in milliseconds.  If you had a standard Unix Epoch time in seconds, you would multiply by 1,000, but that's not what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1.
    `var date = new Date()`

2.
`var date = new Date(unixtime)`

Comment: In your example: What is "unixtime" ?? Maybe you should declare that one too, so people don't get confuse.